# Simple Timer in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, timer

I'm trying to make a simple timer in iOS using Swift.
The program is working fine but whenever my START UIButton is pressed the function of timer starts and runs multiple time as much as the button is pressed.

I want to disable the START UIButton as soon as the timer function starts so that it does not run multiple times.

Please help me for the same.

This is my code of ViewController

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var time = 0.0
    var timer = Timer()

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl: UILabel!

    @IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @IBAction func pause(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        timer.invalidate()
    }

    @IBAction func reset(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        timer.invalidate()
        time = 0.0
        lbl.text = ("0")
    }

    func action()
    {
        time += 0.1
        lbl.text = String(time)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Comment: You can simply disable button into start() method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable your button you can just set it's `isUserInteractionEnabled` property in `start` function:

```
@IBOutlet weak var startButton: UIButton!

@IBAction func start(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    startButton.isEnabled = false
}
```

Then set it back to true in `pause` and `reset` methods:

```
@IBAction func pause(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer.invalidate()
    startButton.isEnabled = true
}

@IBAction func reset(_ sender: UIButton) {
    timer.invalidate()
    startButton.isEnabled = true 
    //the rest of your code
}
```

Comment: It would be better to set the `enabled` property of the button instead of using `userInteractionEnabled`. And it would be `button.userInteractionEnabled = true`, not `button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`. You don't want to call the setter using the getter.

Comment: @rmaddy Totally agree about the first statement, but not about the second. Since swift 3 it is renamed and `button.userInteractionEnabled = true` won't even compile.

Comment: @rmaddy It looks like an intentional renaming for all Bool properties. enabled->isEnabled is also renamed as well as hidden, opaque, focused and a bunch of others ;)

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way to ensure that the timer is only started and stopped once is writing two methods which check the current state (timer is not `nil` if it's currently running):

```
var timer : Timer?

func startTimer()
{
  guard timer == nil else { return }
  timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.action), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  // disable start button
}

func stopTimer()
{
  guard timer != nil else { return }
  timer!.invalidate()
  timer = nil
  // enable start button
}
```

In the methods you can enable/disable the button(s) accordingly.